# In Alamofire,is there any method to detect the Network Reachability Status like AFNetworkReachabilityManager in AFNetworking

Tags: alamofire

Is there any method to detect the Network Reachability Status like AFNetworkReachabilityManager in AFNetworking

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is not. We will be adding this feature in the next release.